# Combine Two Commands in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I know there has to be a simple answer but how can I run both my commands at the same time? I can run one line to create the new directory and name it, then copy items from one folder to another. But how do I create the folder and copy the files into that created folder?

```
    #Creates new directory and names it current date and time.
    New-Item C:\ -type directory -Name ("$(Get-Date -f ddMMyyyy_hhmm)")

    #Copies Data from one directory to another, works good.
    Copy-Item C:\test\* C:\test2
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you just want the command to be one-line or do you want it to all happen in one step?

Comment: If it's possible to do in one line that would be great, but because I started power shell today I wrote out the pseudo code and spent lots of time on the msdn site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the FullName property of the object that New-Item returns as the destination for another command.  i.e.

```
Copy-Item C:\somefolder\* -Destination (New-Item -type Directory -name (Get-Date -f ddMMyyyy_hhmmss)).FullName
```

Comment: Where would I specify a path to where I wanted to copy my files to, would I put the path after Directory?

Comment: You wanted the files to go into the new directory that you just created, right?  If so, there's nothing else to type.  If the two commands are completely unrelated though, then there's no reason to combine them...